# Shutting down another activity using finshActivity(int requestCode)

Tags: android

I want to finish a previously opened activity.Can anyone give me a simple example how this method works. Should I use this method or you have another suggestions on closing previously opened activity?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. Post your code and any issues you have.

Answer (score 1):

Like the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity%28int%29) says:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
...
finishActivity(requestCode);
```